# В чем отличие scrollTo и scrollBy в Android?

Tags: android, прокрутка

В чем отличие scrollTo и scrollBy в Android? Обьясните разницу.

Answer (score 2):

Разница такая же, как и во фразах "проехать до 10-го километра" и "проехать 10 километров".

- `scrollTo` скроллит до указанной позиции.
- `scrollBy` скроллит на указанное количество пикселей.